# how to find edge from data in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, graph, gephi

I'm trying to find the relation (edges) between nodes using Excel and VBA. I will use the output in Gephi, but the data that I have in Excel is too large, and this an example for my question to find the true relations.

If I have this data:

```
  'data for id_books that user_id borrowed
    user_id        id_book     book
    1                55        physic           
    2                55        physic
    2                55        physic
    3                55        physic
    4                55        physic
```

this is the output is show me the users that borrowed the same book from library:

```
    nodes(user_id):       edges(relation between user_id)
                           source,target
      1                    1,2
      2                    1,3
      3                    1,4 
      4                    2,3
                           2,4
                           2,3
                           2,4
```

is that correct to show me 1,2 just once?

Comment: I wrote in the table : I'm trying to find the relation between nodes with excel , and this relation about : borrowing the same book , so it's ok to find node A having relation with node B , but my question is if node B is repeated twice, what will happen for node A ?

Comment: let me ask in a different way : if the users 1,2,3,4 have borrowed the same book but user 2 took this book twice , when we get the edges as output we see the pairs arranged according to their common factor " book" as we see in the table above , but my question is when user 2 took the book twice is it correct to see the edge between it and the other users twice too , e.g : 2,3 2,3 2,4 2,4 ... and if this repeation is wanted and true why 1,2 is not reapeating twice too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two closely related structures in Discrete Mathematics, graphs and multigraphs. A [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)#Multigraph) is a set of nodes and a *set* of pairs of nodes. If you want to define a graph whose nodes are users and whose edges correspond to the relation of having borrowed the same book at least once, then it wouldn't make sense to list an edge like `(1,2)` more than once. On the other hand, in a [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) edges can be repeated. Storing `(1,2)` multiple times would tell you that user 1 and user 2 have borrowed the same book, with at least one of those users having borrowed the book at least twice. If you would find that information useful, use a multigraph. Otherwise use a graph. I would think that something like [Gephi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gephi) would be able to draw both graphs and multigraphs, so in that sense it really is up to you. Note, however, that drawings of multigraphs can be harder to read since they have more visual clutter. I hate cluttered diagrams, so I would probably prefer to use single-edge graphs rather than multi-edge multigraphs, but that is more of a preference on my part. You might have a strong reason to prefer multigraphs in your intended application.

Comment: Gephi cannot btw display multi-graphs, it instead aggregates the weights of the corresponding multi-edges